# Find Acceleration of Coupled Objects With External Forces and Static Friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, friction

**Problem**

The three boxes A, B, C with force F_1, F_2, F_3 push against boxes E, F and the U-shaped object D.

E, F and D counteract with the static friction forces, F_s1, F_s2 and F_s3 respectively, the forces stay constant after maxed out, again u_1, u_2 and u_3 respectively.

All objects are initially at rest.

Movement and forces are constrained to one dimension x, there is no rotation.

The masses of all objects can be assumed to be 1 (each object has mass 1).

What is the acceleration of each object, after the forces have been applied?

**Question**

Intuitively I feel like either nothing moves (accelerates), because static friction is too high, or a group (one of either (A, D, E), (B, E, F), (C, F, D) or (A, B, C, D, E, F)) moves together with the same acceleration. My intuition might be wrong though.

Could you help me to formalize the problem properly and find a general solution? I have been struggeling with this problem for quite a while. Thanks a lot.

Edit: This is not a homework or exercise question. This problem is just an example for a whole class of similar problems that I am looking to solve as part of my work on a physics based game.

Here is a drawing that illustrates the problem (top down view):

[image: Problem]

Comment: I agree with you that one of the given groups will move, but without knowing what the maximum forces are, it's impossible to say which ones.  Also, are the blocks constrained in orientation or are they allowed to rotate?

Comment: You can assume that the forces are known, but I am looking for a general solution or a set of equations, where you plug in the actual force values. No rotation is allowed, it‘s effectively a 1d problem.